# UITableView selected cell separator not shown in iOS 7.1

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I have a very strange problem. Separator line of selected cell in UITableView has not shown in iOS 7. As following Picture:

[image]

So I used the following codes:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // fix for separators bug in iOS 7
    tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didUnhighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // fix for separators bug in iOS 7
    tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
}
```

It solved problem when I used xCode 5 on iOS7.

But as soon as I updated to xCode 5.1 and compiled my app on iOS 7.1, the problem occurred again and none of tricks worked this time.
I used:

1. `cell.clipsToBounds = YES;`

2.`[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPath withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];`

3. Removed my previous code.
4. Tried several separator styles.

and some other tricks. Unfortunately none of them worked this time.

What would be problem? And how can I solve it?

Comment: why are you showing and hiding the separator like this tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;

Comment: What you exactly trying to do ? you want to show/hide the separator on selection ?

Comment: @Basheer_CAD This is ios bug and there were some solution for it.

Comment: post your solution then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally typed following lines of code:

```
[tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
UIView * lineAfterCell = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, cell.frame.size.height + 1, self.view.frame.size.width, .5)];
[lineAfterCell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
[cell addSubview:lineAfterCell];
```

And it worked perfectly.

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary to add your own separator, but I have been unable to get XCode to show its separator, so this worked for me as well.